# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Cursor

Tags: java, android

I know that this question was asked many times before, but I just can't find the right answer for my problem.

I am using Cursor for taking a picture from my Gallery and save it into my ImageView. When I write Cursor into my class and the error pops up I choose Fix project setup and then select `JRE System Library[jre.8.0_45]` to build path and the error is gone. When I click the image from Gallery and it crashes with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  java.awt.Cursor`.

I've checked my dependencies and everything is selected. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Why did you expect that you could just start using the desktop JRE in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the import import `android.database.Cursor;` instead

Comment: How about accepting the answer then? It will help others with a similar problem in the future.